# Form as Popover in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use MaterialUI with custom styled to display form (mostly checkbox) as a popover. I want the checkbox to be colored (before and after it is checked) and the checkmark too, but I am not able to do. Can somebody help me what I am missing. I am able to style the CustomisedButton component though but not the CustomisedTypography. I am not sure what is happening.

```
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

import styled from "styled-components";

export default function BasicPopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomisedButton
        aria-describedby={id}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Filter
      </CustomisedButton>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
      >
        <CustomisedTypography sx={{ p: 2 }}>
          <div>Filter By:</div>

          <span>Status</span>

          <div class="checkbox">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="vehicle2"
              name="vehicle2"
              value="Car"
              className="checkmark"
            />
            <label htmlFor="vehicle2"> On Deck</label>
          </div>

          <div class="checkbox">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="vehicle3"
              name="vehicle3"
              value="Boat"
              className="checkmark"
            />
            <label htmlFor="vehicle3"> In Progress</label>
          </div>



        </CustomisedTypography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}

const CustomisedButton = styled(Button)`
  text-transform: capitalize;
`;

const CustomisedTypography = styled(Typography)`

border: 1px solid blue; // Just to see if this get displayed. Not working either

div{
  border: 1px solid red; // Just to see if this get displayed. Not working either
}

.checkbox label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  
}

.checkbox label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;


  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;


  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: pink;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

 .checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
    line-height: 12px;
}
`;
```

Comment: Try this: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#creating-new-component-variants